# $\mathbb{A}^n _R \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is not Proper Morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Consider the affine $n$-space $\mathbb{A}^n _R=  \operatorname{Spec}(R)(R[X_1,, ..., X_n])$ over arbitrary nontrivial ring $R$. (assume furthermore $n \ge 1$)

I want to show that the related structure morphism $s:\mathbb{A}^n _R \to  \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is ***not proper***.

My considerations:

proper means that $s$ is separated, of finite type and universally closed (so closeness of $s$ is stable under base change).

Since $s$ is a morphism between affine schemes it is separated and obviously of finite type.

So the problem is to find a base change $b: X \to  \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ such that the induced $s': \mathbb{A}^n _R \times_{ \operatorname{Spec}(R)} X \to X$ from diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 \mathbb{A}^n _R \times_{\operatorname{Spec}(R)} X @>{s'}  >> X \\
@VVprV  @VVbV  \\
\mathbb{A}^n _R @>{s}>>  \operatorname{Spec}(R)
\end{CD}
$$

isn't a closed morphism.

Does anybody see how to construct such $X$?

Does there exist a conceptual method to find such $X$ in a sophisticated way or it just a "guessing game"?

Comment: Over a field $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ isnt closed, here $n = 1$ and $X = \mathbb A^1$. Shouldn't be too hard to generalize I assume?

Comment: @PaulK: I'm not sure if I understand correctly how this map is defined. We work with $\mathbb{A}^1 _k $ over field $k$. If $X= \mathbb{A}^1 _k$ then $s': \mathbb{A}^2 _k \cong \mathbb{A}^1 _k \times \mathbb{A}^1 _k \to \mathbb{A}^1 _k$. On the level of rings it is a map $k[X] \to k[X,Y]$. I don't see why the assignment $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ make sense. Or how to interpret it?

Comment: @PaulK: Set theoretically your map looks like a map $m: \mathbb{A}^2 _k \to \mathbb{A}^2 _k$

Comment: It's a map $\mathbb A^2 \to \mathbb A^1$ isn't it?

Comment: @PaulK: ah yes yes I think that by $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ you assign to every prime $p_{xy}:= <(X-x, Y-y)>$ (note here $x,y \in k$ and $X,Y$ indeterminants) a prime $p=<(T -xy)>$ in $\mathbb{A}^1 _k$, right? Or did I misunderstood you? If yes, then the problem is that in addition your $k$ has also to be algebraically closed since if not then there could occure prime ideals in $\mathbb{A}^2 _k$ not of the shape $ (X-x, Y-y)$ and then your map in not everywhere defined

Comment: @KarlPeter On the level of rings, this maps is $k[T]\to k[X,Y], T\mapsto XY$.

Comment: @Roland: so this the "extended" version for arbitrary fields of Paul K's map. And the joke is that the image of $V(XY-1)$ is $\mathbb A^1 \backslash \{0\}$, so not closed...